# How to pass an struct array to my struct function

Tags: go

So, i have my slice renamed for using in functions, which one connected to array (like a class methods).

```
type Points []Point


func (p Points) Isset(ip Point) bool {
     for _, i := range p {
         if i.Hash == ip.Hash {
             return true
         }
     }
     return false
}
```

But it's doesn't matter, coz in another function, which one tried to pass slice with type Points, i have some trouble...

Here is example:

```
func (p Points) Merge(ip Points) {
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

In first function - i can access to my `p` variable as array. In second - `p` - just empty array. But if i change type of passed variable - everything will be fine.

What should i do... I need to specify me merge function. And this solution look's like awesome, but doesn't work.

Comment: Please show a running example which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand, this is a play example showing both functions working as expected as far as I can tell.

https://play.golang.org/p/n5ch-Wqbil

Perhaps you are running into some problem calling one function from the other (like calling Isset from Merge maybe?)  In that case @Games' answer will probably still apply.

**EDIT** this example show what I **think** you are probably trying to do.  https://play.golang.org/p/CNEt-poKdN and it seems to work just fine (though has N^2 time performance)

Comment: Magic... Can't repeat on my laptop. Keep trying.

Comment: When you say "Can't repeat on my laptop", what does that mean?  Can you paste your entire code into a playground and link it in your question?

Comment: How would you create an append function for Points, where you can just do `Points.Append(Point)`?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You would certainly need a pointer receiver in that case since you would be modifying the receiver.

Comment: Oh my god... I'am so sorry, but i just create a slice of points like `var res Points` in another function... And this one a cause, i guess. Now everything works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to say that `Points` is a reference to an instance of `Points`. You can do this by the following:

```
func (p *Points) Isset(ip Point) bool {
     for _, i := range p {
         if i.Hash == ip.Hash {
             return true
         }
     }
     return false
}
```

Notice how we set `*Points` instead of `Points`. This tells go that we want to work with the instance of the `Points` struct that we have called the method from.

Comment: Oh wait, but this function working well. And *Points doesn't working, coz we using type as alias for slice.

Merge doesn't working, not Isset.

Comment: @AlexandrButenko see if the same change for Merge works now.